# Did the new Outlook Design for Mac break Applescript?

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I was using a good deal of AppleScript with MS Outlook. With the release 16.49 the new design came also with it. However all my scripts seem to not work anymore. Any ideas?

If I switch to the old design then all scripts work again.

Just as an example:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    selection
end tell
```

This normally gives back something like:
*incoming message id 140096 of application "Microsoft Outlook"*

But with the new design it just returns:
*missing value*

Answer (score 2):

The feature is [on the roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=88537), and is supposed to be available <s>June 2022</s> November 2023.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31534550)

Comment: as of July 2022 this has now been pushed back to March 2023... Argg

Comment: It's now March 2023 - will it be released!? I'm not hopeful...

Comment: Current time: `Rollout Start: November 2023`

Comment: .. and now rollout starts December 2024. What's that sound? Could it be the sound of a can being kicked repeatedly down a road?

Answer (score 1):

To save a trip to the [Microsoft 365-Roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=88537), it is now reporting November 2023 for AppleScript support.

Answer (score -1):

I've heard the new version with the new interface is not Applescriptable yet, but it may be if you can use the old interface. I don't have the new version so I can't say for sure.